# Wrap content not working and scroll stopped working

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, tablet, android-relativelayout

Wrap content not working and scroll stopped working.

Hi, I'm developing an app for Android and I have noticed that my app works perfectly in smartphones, however in Tablets in Portrait mode it adds a huge space and the ScrollView stops working.

**Smartphone's view:**

[image: Phone view]

**Tablet's view:**

[image: Tablet view]

**My XML code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/descAbout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgSpaceApps"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="115dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/spaceApps" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgNasaLogo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="115dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/nasaLogo" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="@string/lblContact2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblOurEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="@string/lblContactUs"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="@string/lblVisit"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="@string/lblSpecialGreeting"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="@string/url7"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="@string/url8"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="@string/url6"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="@string/url5"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="@string/url1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="@string/url2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="@string/url3"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="@string/url4"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="@string/lblPPrivacy"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="@string/url9"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/supernova" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="@string/About6"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

If I remove the properties of:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

The result is the same:

[image: Other result]

I am testing in Android 6 and 7, also, the minimum SDK is 21.

Does anyone have experienced this situation? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not a solution; but for the cause: It's because you have a RelativeLayout with `height=wrap_content`, and a child view with `alignParentBottom=true`. This makes the RelativeLayout fill all available space and place the child at the bottom. This is the whole screen because the scrollview has `fillviewport=true`. It can be somewhat annoying behaviour when working with RelativeLayout. You'll have to rethink your layout structure or change some of these attributes.

Comment: Hi @RobCo, it doesn't work: https://ibb.co/gUEQxc

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the error with your code. Using Android Studio 3.3 plus some Tablet emulators for API levels 22 and 24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment the cause is the RelativeLayout that holds the images.
RelativeLayout can cause unexpected results when used with 'wrap_content' where it will actually try to match its parent and lay out the children at the edges.

In this case, the RelativeLayout is pretty useless anyway; you can remove it and slightly change the attributes of the child LinearLayout:

```
        ...
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgSpaceApps"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="115dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/spaceApps" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgNasaLogo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="115dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/nasaLogo" />
        </LinearLayout>
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/descAbout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgSpaceApps"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="115dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/spaceApps" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgNasaLogo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="115dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/nasaLogo" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="@string/lblContact2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblOurEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="@string/lblContactUs"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="@string/lblVisit"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="@string/lblSpecialGreeting"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="@string/url7"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="@string/url8"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="@string/url6"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="@string/url5"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="@string/url1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="@string/url2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="@string/url3"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="@string/url4"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="@string/lblPPrivacy"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="@string/url9"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/supernova" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="@string/About6"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```